# Laplace equation without azimuthal symmetry

Tags: electrostatics, potential

Statement of my problem is that :

> A solid dielectric cylinder of dielectric constant $k$ is placed in a uniform electric
> field $ E_0 \hat{z} $ **perpendicular to its length.** Obtain an expression for the potential inside
> and outside the cylinder.

What bothering me is that there isn't $z$ symmetry in the question and I have tried to solve the question fundamentally by imposing the Laplace equation and using separation of variable (using $\Phi $ symmetry) But in that way I am getting all the variables equal to zero.

Comment: The symmetry, that the system should not care about $\varphi$, is the definition of azimuthal symmetry. Not to say that your problem is easier to solve, since 2D radial length and the z distance will still be correlated, but at least you do have azimuthal symmetry.